# What is the difference between deep and shallow cloning?

Tags: javascript, arrays, clone

If I use splice to clone an array it gives me a shallow copy, what is missing? It seems I get back multilevel arrays so it is not the depth of the array if I understand correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a shallow copy, if arrays (or object properties) are references to objects, then only the references are copied.

```
var a = [{name: "Bob"}];
var b = a.slice(0);
b[0].name = "Tom";
alert(a[0].name); // "Tom"
```

A "deep" copy makes sure that the result contains new copies of all referenced objects from the original data structure. Performing a deep copy can be problematic, depending on the nature of the objects involved.

Comment: thanx, so that means in deep cloning all the values are copied and lose their connection to the original object?

Comment: Yes - in a deep copy, the new (result) array or object will have its own fresh copies of everything from the original. Usually, that's done recursively too.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to understand deep and shallow cloning is:

1. In shallow cloning if reference object is present it will not
   serialize.
2. In deep cloning both object reference and current both serialize.
       Instead with this there are so many things come into picture like
       pool,object references etc